# Save an Excel-File without Macros. Excel VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel-Document with macros that my customer should fill out  save pressing a button.

[image]

Under the button is just this macro:

```
Sub filesave()
    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

The problem is that as default option you get to save the document as macro enabled excel workbook.

[image]

How can do show as default non macro enabled excel format or not show the posibility to save the document as macro enabled document in oder to make sure that the macros will not be saved in the filled out copy of the document?

**Some ideas about how the code should look like?**

Comment: All you have to do is SaveAs .xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetSaveAsFilename` to let the user choose a location and filename and then save with [Workbook.SaveAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) by choosing a file format from [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel).

```
Public Sub SaveFileAs()
    Dim FileToSave As Variant
    FileToSave = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="xlsx Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

    If FileToSave <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileToSave, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Else
        'user chose cancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How without asking the user, just by converting `.xlsm` into `.xlsx`, then deleting the `.xlsm`?

Comment: @lalebarde everything you need is in this answer and the linked documents. What have you tried so far? Probably better to open up a new question according [ask] with your attempt and an explanation where you got stuck or errors.